# fade in only works after page is in view port

Tags: jquery, viewport

this is my code

```
<img class="Buble2" 
src="http://www.spidycode.com/testing/revibe/images/Bubble-8.png">
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $(".Buble2").hide(0).delay(500).fadeIn(3000)
  });

 </script>
```

this fade in works perfectly.but I need that to work the animation after the content is in the viewport.how can I do this

Comment: Explain "page is in the viewport"?

Comment: `but I need that to work the animation after the page is in the viewport`=> can you explain this?

Comment: The problem I have is that the given animation(images) is placed off screen due to lots of content before it so by the time a user scrolls down to it, the animation has already finished.

Comment: so you want to trigger the animation when the div is visible ?

Comment: yes @madalin ivascu